# Cron job is not running on centos

Tags: python, cron, centos, mysql-backup

i am setting cron job on centos.

*/10 * * * * /root/var/mysqlbackup.sh

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

/usr/local/bin/mysqlbackup.py (file permission is 755)

```
/var/mysqlbackup.sh
```

**content of mysqlbackup.sh:**

```
#! /bin/sh
cd  usr/local/bin
python mysqlbackup.py --cnf /etc/my.cnf --todir /var/backup
```

while its working manually. but its not working in cron job and i am not getting any error.

Comment: What happens if you put `/root/var/mysqlbackup.sh 1> somewhere 2> somewhereelse` into your cron tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your sh file path :

```
*/10 * * * * /var/mysqlbackup.sh > /var/log/yourloggilename.log
```

Note: log file must have 755 permissions.

**content of mysqlbackup.sh:**

```
echo "Running.."
cd  /usr/local/bin
echo "backup file is creating...."
python mysqlbackup.py --cnf /etc/my.cnf --todir /var/backup
echo "backup file created"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add `set -x` at the beginning of `mysqlbackup.sh` it will turn your script in debug mode.

Launch a terminal and type `tail -f /var/log/messages` to get debug info from your script (when launched through cron).

After launch another terminal and `tail -f /var/log/cron` then you will see if anything goes weird with your cron.